# How to quote in the title of a thesis in APA style?

Tags: thesis, writing-style, quotation

I am writing my bachelor thesis (in psychology) and I am planning to use a quote from the series *Game of Thrones* as my title. More specifically, my title is:

> ‘The lone wolf dies but the pack survives’: The influence of perceived social consensus on the fear of death

Now, I am really unsure how to quote this. According to APA Style, I would have to write the producer, director and the year in brackets but it doesn’t make much sense to this for the title (it looks stupid).

Is there any possibility to quote in the title using footnotes?

Comment: Maybe just leave the quote out and just use the subtitle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you would need to provide a full citation for a quote that's used that way.

It's not uncommon to use a small quote at the beginning of an article to provide some "flavor text," as in the picture below. In cases like this, some attribution is given, but the quote source isn't included in the APA Reference list.

[image: example of quote in article]

I would think that if you provided the full Game of Thrones passage as a "flavor text" quote at the very beginning of the article (including an informal attribution), that would be enough to get the job done. It's not too different from articles that use a quote from an interview in a title and then to provide the full context of that quote later in the article (e.g., http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/09518398.2010.495091).